# Visibility about the UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

In Interface Builder, I did't give the UIBarButtonItem a title, then the UIBarButtonItem was not appear when it was running.
I want to control it in my code, but when I set the title property of UIBarButtonItem to @"", the bar button was not disappear instead.
I don't know if there is a property to control the visibility of UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationItem.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: To clarify: You want to do be able to make the UITabBarButton disappear using code. You have attempted this by setting the title property to @"", but it did not disappear?

Comment: The question is not for a UITabBar button, he's asking about a UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can also try `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`